# Is it bad for SEO to cache bust CSS and JS using a VERSION variable?

Tags: seo

To prevent CSS & JS changes caching, I'm using a version variable that gets updated when new changes are made. Is it bad for SEO if it sees something like somewebsite.com/stylesheet.css?version=2?

I can't change the method of cache busting for this entire project, as it has already been built this way - please only advise on whether this is bad for SEO, and if so, is there a way to improve it?

Comment: I can't see any reason that cache busting can have a negative effect on SEO. It may even help. Googlebot aggressively caches so this would protect you from it using old versions of resources.

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone having issues with cache busting and SEO. I use it on my own site and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.